# Would Analytic Philosophy benefit from a name change?

Tags: semantics, analytic-philosophy

The moniker 'Analytic' for the currently predominant academic regimen in philosophy does not seem to convey much about its point and aim. Has there ever been or is there any type of movement or call for a change in its description or title within the field? The goal of philosophy is to seek clarity and meaning.

For clarities sake would the title, 'Mathematically Oriented Semantic Logic' make any sense?

Comment: I doubt if any serious challenge has ever been proposed. Arguably, it is mathematics which is oriented towards the analytical methods of the logician. One simply needs to understand what "analysis" means in this context.

Comment: For myself, I agree with those who dislike the term 'analytic philosophy' because of its association with Russell's vision of philosophy as being concerned with conceptual analysis. I don't object to 'analytical philosophy', though even that is somewhat too narrow.

Comment: 'Mathematically Oriented Semantic Logic' make any sense? NO

Comment: I love the irony of asking whether AP — a school that rests on a presumption of strict denotation, or a one-to-one mapping of linguistic symbols onto their real-world referents — might benefit from a name change.

Comment: I don't have this impression of analytic philosophy at all (except maybe early analytic philosophy, logical positivism, which is a dead movement). Nowadays analytic philosophy is more than just philosophical logic, philosophy of language, and philosophy of science. [It also includes metaphysics, epistemology, ethics, aesthetics, political philosophy, philosophy of religion, etc.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analytic_philosophy#Contemporary_analytic_philosophy).

Comment: @Adam Sharpe- All the sub-groupings you mention have no distinguishing feature. I'm a metaphysician and epistemologist and a few more of those you mentioned, but my take on what constitutes philosophy does not include anything analytic.Not sure where that leads but perhaps to some type of clarification?

Comment: @Ted Wrigley- Help me understand, what see on this site is typically logical formulas which use a signed letters like p or q, which appear to act as factors into which any value can be plugged to form a generalization which has no 'real world' referent.

Comment: @CharlesMSaunders: Yes, that's the essence of symbolic logic. But Russell and the early 20th century analytic philosophers wanted more than that. They wanted (more or less) to preclude metaphysics by reconstructing philosophy in the mold of the natural sciences. Thus they spent their efforts on mathematical logic, on the presumption that a properly mathematicized logic (like a properly mathematicized physics) would have strong correspondence to the empirical world. An interesting idea, and brilliantly executed, but ultimately doomed by the broadly conventional nature of language.

Comment: I always thought that your take on philosophy is analytic through and through. Spinoza's Ethics is modeled on Euclid's Elements whose demonstrations are crafted through what Greeks called [analysis-and-synthesis](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/analysis/s2.html). "Analytic" is certainly more descriptive than "continental" and sufficiently vague to pour in what meaning one prefers. 'Mathematically Oriented Semantic Logic' is too verbose and narrow. In any case, concerns over clarity and descriptiveness are not a major factor in establishing names historically, in any area, force of habit is.

Comment: I would be more inclined, somewhat cynically, to say the difference now is between English language philosophy, and that done in basically any other language. I am saddened by the retreat of English language philosophy into a stuffy corner of academia, and what seems to me a failure of nerve to bring to bear now, the tools of philosophy on to issues of the day, and lived developing culture. But then, as I see it a philosopher should aspire to be somewhere between Wittgenstein's model of therapist, and Durkheim's model of shaman, actively participating in our developing social intelligence.

Comment: @Conidold - Spinoza's use of the 'more geometrica' has nothing to do with Euclid. See. John Carriero's Spinoza- 'Conatus' in Melamud's ' Spinoza- A Critical Guide'.

Comment: @CriglCragl- Visit Academia or Philpapers to view my work. And see a sample of, 'no failure of nerve'. Cheers,

Comment: @CharlesMSaunders: As in https://philpeople.org/profiles/charles-milton-saunders & https://independent.academia.edu/CharlesMSaunders5? You miss my point, those papers are squarely academic philosophy. My great philosophical heroes are William Morris & Sen no Rikyu. Wittgenstein wrote a commentary on The Golden Bough, as well as grappling with logic & language. Philosophers shouldn't just speak to other philosophers, but engage themselves with their culture,  and so their culture with their work - like De Beauvoir and Camus did.

Comment: @Sorry to have wasted your time. Regards,